# How to detect an ACF row content type

Tags: php, css, wordpress, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to build a gallery using fancybox on a wordpress site. These gallery items are advanced custom fields (ACFS) repeaters.

The problem is, the client wants only some gallery items to be links, as some will be just colored boxes with text, therefore, should not be a link and should not open in the fancybox.

As you can see in the code below, I am calling all rows in the repeater, and placing them in their own divs, with hrefs.

How is it possible to detect if the row is an image or a text box, and add href accordingly?

```
<?php
if( have_rows('p3projectsres') ):
    while ( have_rows('p3projectsres') ) : the_row(); ?>
         <div class="s3block">
        <p> <a href="<?php the_sub_field('p3projectreshires'); ?>" rel="lightbox" title="<?php the_sub_field('p3projectresdescription'); ?>">

                <!-- <div class="locationscript"><?php the_sub_field('p3projectreslocation'); ?></div> -->
                <div class="s3blockblurb">
                    <div class="scribe7">   
                        <?php the_sub_field('p3projectresblurb'); ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="s3blockfaded"><?php the_sub_field('p3projectreslocation'); ?></div>

                </div>
                <img src="<?php the_sub_field('p3projectrespreview'); ?>" /> 
            </a></p>
        </div>
    <?php  endwhile;
else : endif;
?>
```

See the problem here, under "our work":  [www.entirecreative.com/stone](http://www.entirecreative.com/stone)

Comment: You are trying to determine the type of the repeater subfield?

Comment: And are you using a Flexible Content field or a Repeater? If it's a repeater do you just have an image field + text field per row with one filled in?

Comment: Can you post your field configuration?

Comment: And if you are using ACF4 or ACF5

Comment: Thanks for the reply doublesharp,

Yes, it's a repeater. I've included links to the wordpress dashboard view of the repeater set up, as well as it's input.
1. https://goo.gl/photos/c7FB9CjQFHnhvdCx7
2. https://goo.gl/photos/5CJjBZ39eSn7vTCF6


I see there's a checkbox option within the repeater, would it be possible to add one, and call it 'image', then if it's possible, in the code above, add another if loop, asking if image checked, then add link to div (project image), if unchecked, place in div with no link (colored box)

Comment: Just to clarify, what you want to do is if there is no image on the row do not include the link?

Comment: i'm using ACF pro 5.3.1

Comment: yes, just have no link, so if the user does click on one of those yellowish boxes with the blurb, nothing happens.

i can leave the link blank, (by not adding the link hi res image) but it still is contained within a href, with rel="lightbox", so it just opens nothing in the lightbox..

Comment: Does it always have a preview?

Comment: Yeah, the preview is either an image, or a image of the yellow box. This way it's easy for the client to add themselves. (i know, would be very easy to use .nthchild, but that defeat the purpose of using ACF)

Comment: Wasn't sure so I included a check for it as well, just use `get_sub_field()` first to check if the field is set on the repeater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`get_sub_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_sub_field/) to retrieve the value for a field (as opposed to echoing it with `the_sub_field()`). If the value is not set, it will return `false`, so it can be used in an `if` statement to only output the `A` open/close tags if the "p3projectreshires" sub field is set on the repeater row. You can also conditionally include the preview image by checking "p3projectreshires".

```
<?php
if( have_rows('p3projectsres') ):
    while ( have_rows('p3projectsres') ) : the_row(); ?>
         <div class="s3block"><p> 
         <!-- 
             check to see if there is a value for "p3projectreshires" 
             and if there is open the A tag
         -->
         <?php if ( get_sub_field('p3projectreshires') ) : ?>
             <a href="<?php the_sub_field('p3projectreshires'); ?>" rel="lightbox" title="<?php the_sub_field('p3projectresdescription'); ?>">
         <?php endif; ?>

                <div class="s3blockblurb">
                    <div class="scribe7">   
                        <?php the_sub_field('p3projectresblurb'); ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="s3blockfaded"><?php the_sub_field('p3projectreslocation'); ?></div>

                </div>
                <!-- Only include the preview image if it is set -->
                <?php if ( get_sub_field('p3projectrespreview') ) : ?>
                     <img src="<?php the_sub_field('p3projectrespreview'); ?>" /> 
                <?php endif; ?>
         <!-- 
             check to see if there is a value for "p3projectreshires" 
             and if there is close the A tag
         -->
         <?php if ( get_sub_field('p3projectreshires') ) : ?>
            </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </p></div>
    <?php  endwhile;
else : endif;
?>
```

Comment: Doublesharp, my gratitude is stronger than a thousand waves. 

I have spoken to so many people over this issue, and no one seems to even understand the problem, let alone offer a solution.

I'm gonna go have a play right now with your wise words of wizardy,

Thanks again!

Comment: Ha, thanks :) Shameless promotion: you might want to check out my [Validated Field](https://wordpress.org/plugins/validated-field-for-acf/) plugin which wraps existing ACF fields to give you even more control (read only, validation, input masking, etc). Just finished up a complete rewrite for 2.0, should be releasing it soon.

Comment: If you are still doing dev and could beta the new version I would be really grateful, you can find it here: https://github.com/doublesharp/validated-field-for-acf

Comment: Oh i owe you more than one, but i'm not sure what you mean? 
'beta the new version?'
lol if you can't tell, i am incredibly new to wordpress